# how to append nested divs by jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, append

I have below section code in slider show:

```
<div id="st_swiper_block_55">
<img class="st_swiper_image" src="https://domain.ir/upload/stswiper/1slide.jpg" alt=""width="2000" height="750">  
 </div>
```

and I want add nested dive after img tag by jquery:

```
<div class="hot-spot" x="300" y="43">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <div class="img-row">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/170/128/?random">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

I try but don't work:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
var divnested = '<div class="hot-spot" x="300" y="43">';
divnested += '<div class="circle"></div>';
divnested += '<div class="tooltip">';
divnested + ' <div class="img-row">';
divnested + ' <img src="https://picsum.photos/170/128/?random" alt="Jurong Lake Gardens #1"  width="170" height="128">';
divnested + ' </div>';
divnested + '</div>';
divnested + '</div>';
$("#st_swiper_block_55").append($('divnested'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing a selector string in a jQuery object to be appended, instead of the `divnested` variable. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divnested = '<div class="hot-spot" x="300" y="43"><div class="circle"></div><div class="tooltip"><div class="img-row"><img src="https://picsum.photos/170/128/?random" alt="Jurong Lake Gardens #1"  width="170" height="128"></div></div></div>';
  $("#st_swiper_block_55").append(divnested);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="st_swiper_block_55">
  <img class="st_swiper_image" src="https://dev.domain.com/upload/stswiper/1slide.jpg" alt="" width="2000" height="750">
</div>
```

As a side note, be careful adding your own non-standard attributes to HTML elements; `x` and `y` in this case. If you want to apply metadata to an element use `data` attributes instead.

Comment: thanks but don't work. Could it be because of the slider of images?I'm using  from prestashop cms and swiper slider module

Comment: The only way I can see this not working, other than a configuration error on your side, is that the `#st_swiper_block_55` element isn't in the DOM when the page loads. Check the console for errors, and ensure the element is available when you run this code

Answer (score 1):

`$('divnested')` is looking for a tag `<divnested></divnested>` within the DOM and it does not exist

Just append the string as a variable

```
$("#st_swiper_block_55").append(divnested);
```